# Function that detects click outside of element runs when click is inside of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to close an element when I detect a click outside of the element itself, but it seems to be closing the element anyway whenever I click on it.

EDIT: Figured it out.

Comment: I cannot see this class in your html `$(".nav-container")`. can you post your html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your code, `var container = $(".nav-container");` should be `var container = $("#nav-container");` you are searching for nav-container as a class rather than an id, # = id, . = class

Answer (score 0):

Try this script.

you are using class (`var container = $(".nav-container");`) instead of id `var container = $("#nav-container");` here

```
    $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        var container = $("#nav-container");
        if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {

        $('#nav-container').removeClass('open-nav');
        $('#mask').removeClass('active-mask');
        $('body').removeClass('no-overflow');
        }
    });
```